# Multiple php requests simultaneously, second request doesn't finishe until first finishes

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp, php-7.4

When I am using XAMP Server with PHP 5.6

- sleep(10) // sleep for 10 seconds and call other localhost php file, it will work smoothly.

When I am using XAMP Server with PHP 7.4.9

- sleep(10) // sleep for 10 seconds and call other localhost file, it will hang until first finishes

-- Anything I need to change XAMP configuration for request will not wait until first finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### File1.php

```
<?php

session_start();
sleep(1);
echo "I am File2";

?>
```

### File2.php

```
<?php

session_start();
sleep(10);
echo "I am File2";

?>
```

When you run above File2.php first and after run File1.php still need to finish the running process of File2.php

When you session_start(); after you are not writing session then you have to close the session using session_write_close();

### File1.php

```
<?php

session_start();
session_write_close();
sleep(1);
echo "I am File2";

?>
```

### File2.php

```
<?php

session_start();
session_write_close();
sleep(10);
echo "I am File2";

?>
```

Now you can run File2.php and after File1.php then you will execute File1.php first